# Named constant in variable definition context

Tags: fortran, definition, ellipse

I have to compute the circumference of an ellipse using an integral. My Fortran 90 code is:

```
MODULE integral
  REAL(8) :: Is, It,  d
  REAL(8), PARAMETER :: a=0, b= 2*ACOS(-1.0)
  INTEGER :: i, j, n

CONTAINS

  FUNCTION f(x)
    REAL(8) :: x, f, a, b 
    f=SQRT((a**2 * (COS(x))* *2) + (b* *2 * (SIN(x))**2))
  END FUNCTION f

  FUNCTION simpson(f, a, b, Is, n)
    REAL(8) :: Is, a, b,  d

    INTERFACE    
      FUNCTION f(x)
        REAL(8) f,x
      END FUNCTION
    END INTERFACE

   Is=0
   d=(b-a)/n !
   DO i=1, n-1, 2
       Is=Is+f(a+d*(i-1))*d/3.
       Is=Is+f(a+d*i)*d*4/3.
       Is=Is+f(a+d*(i+1))*d/3.
   ENDDO

  END FUNCTION
END MODULE


PROGRAM ellipse
  USE integral 
  IMPLICIT NONE


    WRITE(*,FMT="(A)",ADVANCE="no") "Length of the semi-major axis[m]: "
    READ(*,*)a
    WRITE(*,FMT="(A)",ADVANCE="no") "Length of the semi-minor axis[m]: "
    READ(*,*)b
    WRITE(*,'(1x,E14.5)') "[m]: " 
  END DO  
END PROGRAM  ellipse
```

but I get two error messages by debugging, namely:

```
Named constant "a (or b)" in variable definition context (element in READ)
```

Does anybody have an idea how can I fix that? I tried it with defining different constants / variables, but it didn't work as well. I am opened to ideas and would be extremely grateful, if somebody helped me with this. It has been bugging me for quite the time now!

Comment: a and b are defined in your module as PARAMETER, so they are constants, and you are trying to read (therefore change) them in the main program that uses this module.

Comment: You cannot modify a PARAMETER constant. That is the purpose of PARAMETER to be a constant, non-modifiable.

Comment: Also, If you indent your code more consistently (as I have done) you will see that there is an END DO in the main program, but no DO. Also be advised that `REAL(8)` is ugly and non-portable and you should avoid it if you are learning the language.

Comment: Thank you both a lot! Now it works, but after I debug, I type values for a and b  to test the code, but I get only a message "NaN". Any ideas what causes the operation to be undefined?

Comment: Give us the exact code, either [edit] the question to rewrite it to the new problem, or ask a new question. Because there are no answers yet you can rewrite this question completely without asking a new one.